# Laptops and batteries left plugged in

Tags: laptop, battery, battery-life

What kind of batteries can be left plugged in and not suffer any side effects such as less battery life or exploding?

I was told some laptops and even some apples can be left plugged in continuous and not suffer any issues.

I've not found any cheatsheets yet that explain each kind of battery with their pros/cons and the best way to handle them.

Comment: This type of battery does not exist.  A battery at a basic level os a chemical reaction.  Additionally there are only so many times a battery can be charged.  Most laptop batteries have smart chips to avoid a continious charge.  But even an battery that comes with an Apple laptop shouldn't be left plugged with the battery attached ( unless of course it cannot be removed ) and if thats the case it was designed for that to happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Batteries suffer irreversible incremental damage with every charge-discharge cycle. That's why the better rechargeable vendors and better OEMs tell you how many charge-discharge cycles you will get. Apple has no better tech than anyone else, they just choose nicer parts and a shinier box.

When you buy a laptop, you're stuck with the battery type the OEM chose when they glued the parts together and slapped their label on it. So, when you go to buy next time, add that to your list of specifications.

Apple, Lenovo, and every other laptop manages the battery for you, with the number one priority your safety. When a battery goes BOOM that's not anyone's intent.

The [Rechargeable Battery Applications Handbook](http://books.google.com/books/about/Rechargeable_Batteries_Applications_Hand.html?id=JWL-t4syQ_UC) goes into quite a bit of detail on the subject, but battery charge cycles is just one factor in battery choice; charge time, charge capacity, safety, ease of use, reliability, and the ability to manage the charge process automagically are all important. I used to manage a Battery Room at a phone company, with over a thousand batteries to test and maintain. Be thankful your lappie does it for you.

As for me, I just budget for a replacement jumbo battery every year for every laptop which leaves my house, it's easier that way. And, I'm happy that the industry has pretty much settled on Li-ion for the moment, far better than Ni-Cd, Ni-MH, Ni-air, Li-air or lead acid gel cells, IMHO.